# Want to pass in returned data to my custom callback within jQuery's $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Basically I'm creating my own callback and passing it into my method called `_ajaxCall()`.

`_ajaxCall()` takes the following parameters:

`data` = an object containing the user submitted data to be POSTed to my server
`postURL` = the url to post to
`callback` = a function expression to be called upon successful return of data from the server.

Here is the _ajaxCall() method:

```
_ajaxCall: function (data, postURL, callback) {
  $.post(postURL, {
    data : data
  }, 'json').done(function (returned) {
    switch(returned.success) {
      case true:
        typeof callback === 'function' && callback(returned);
        break;
    }
  }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (status !== 200) {
      window.location = document.URL;
    }
  });
}

commentUpdate : function(self) {
  var postURL = '/submission/comment/' + self.attributes.commentId;

  var data = {
    action: self.attributes.action,
    commentId : self.attributes.commentId,
    comment: self.attributes.comment
  };

  var callback = function(returned) {
    if (returned.success === true) {
      // do something in here
    } else {
      // do other crap here
    }
  };

  this._ajaxCall(data, postURL, callback);
}
```

But it's not passing `returned` to my custom callback() method. Why?

Comment: If you add `console.log(returned)` before `switch(returned.success)` and before `if (returned.success === true)` what are you see?

Comment: @Victor `Object {comment: "asdoadsfoijasjiodfiojasdfijoasdfijoasdf", commentId: "5163ce756aa8fe5d1c0000fc", submissionId: "513d386eb99f8b1ca500004c", success: true, time: "just now"} ` But it won't go into callback().

Comment: try doing something like : typeof callback === 'function' && commentUpdate.callback(returned);

Comment: @Burimi that won't work. It's a function expression within an object literal, plus I don't want to hardcode commentUpdate as a dependency since this ajaxCall method is a modular method used in many places.

Comment: If you add `console.log(callback)` before `switch(returned.success)` and what do you see?

Comment: `callback` function is probably out of scope. Creating function, say `commentUpdateCallback` in upper scope and sending it as a `callback` can help.

Comment: Why does both your switch statement and your if condition check for `success` to be `true`? `// do other crap here` will never be reached.

Comment: [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) does expect its second argument to be the `data` itself, not an object with a `data` property (as in [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Comment: @Bergi because my custom callback determines what to do with the DOM after a success or failure. Within the ajax callback method on error, I log it, and redirect the user to the appropriate page (if necessary). Sending `data` as a custom object to `$.post()` is perfectly valid and I do it all over the place.

Comment: @bob_cobb: No, my point was that your custom callback *cannot* determine whether there was failure because it *only* is called when `returned.success` was true.

Comment: @Bergi Ahhhhh!!! Yes. I need a case for `false` and then call the same callback and it *should* work.